# Migrating TFS 2015 to TFS 2018 on new hardware and database

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015, tfs-migration

We have TFS 2015 Update 3 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1 and 
SQL Server 2012. We like to move to online VSTS/Azure DevOps.

For this, we couldn't find any specific document. What we found is that we will need to move to latest 2 versions of TFS i.e. either TFS 2018 Update 2 or 3 before we can migrate to Azure DevOps.

What is the best process step by step to do this?

Answer (score 2):

- First of all, check the [Requirements and compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/tfs/server/requirements?view=vsts) for TFS 2018 and prepare the hardware according to the requirements.
- **Create a backup to the current SQL database.**
- Upgrade the tfs according [this](https://www.benday.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/benday-tfs2018-install-guide-v1.1.pdf) detailed guide.

I recommend read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/upgrade/get-started) Microsoft article about TFS upgrades.

In addition, you can find [here](http://mohamedradwan.com/2018/01/16/upgrade-to-tfs-2018-has-been-done-in-production/)  nice tutorial - "Upgrade to TFS 2018 Has Been Done in Production".